# ASP.NET Page.ParseControl very slow with Apache/Mono

Tags: c#, asp.net, apache, ubuntu, mono

I'm currently porting an ASP.NET 2.0 application to Apache/Mono (Ubuntu 13.10).

The application uses XSLT to create ASP.NET controls from dynamic content. It does so by using the (infamous) Page.ParseControl(string) method.

Some pages might have >500 dynamic controls. Calling ParseControl on them still used to take only a few milliseconds on IIS/Windows and is only done on initial page-load. For async. post-backs, only a small number of those controls is re-created (like the one that was "clicked") to optimize that stuff.

Now to my problem with Mono:
ParseControl takes between 300-1500 ms for EACH call. Passing those "500 controls" in a loop would probably take forever, so I already optimized it:

1. Put ALL controls in a wrapper-DIV
2. Call ParseControl on that
3. Extract all single elements via C# code

This takes exactly the same time as parsing only 1. The cost of ParseControl seems to be calling it at all I guess. Also it is only that slow, if I pass "new" content to it (so there seems to be some caching already).

ParseControl creates files in /tmp and then starts the ASP.NET-compiler on them as far as I can see. How could I speed this up?
The Mono-sources are full of TODOs refering to that functionallity and it no longer works at all with Ubuntu 14.04 (throws "System.Web.Compilation.CompilationException", see http://mono.1490590.n4.nabble.com/CS1576-after-upgrade-to-Ubuntu-14-04-1-td4663599.html)

Comment: *completely broken* is not enough to describe something, please tell us the error you get

Comment: For now I came up with a few workarounds: To fix "ParseControl" on Mono 3.x (Ubuntu 14.04), I'm now using "LoadControl" with temporary "ascx" files (note: Still very slow). For speeding things up I'm now using a self-written "ParseControl"-Engine that is based on http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/ This actually workd better than expected, so I might post it here once I consider it "stable".

Answer (score 0):

Here is my own implementation of ParseControl. It is far from being complete, so don't expect too much.

Results to expect:

Non-server-controls will be put into "LiteralControl"s.

Supported server-controls (runat="server"):

- "HtmlControl"s
- Controls from "System.Web" assembly
- Custom controls defined in "Web.config"

Others (like user controls) should be easy to add (I'm not using them in my project right now).

The result (if it works) will be something similar to what "Page.ParseControl" does, but NOT THE SAME.

Performance:
I use some caching to speed things up, but it will still be ~50% slower on Windows than "Page.ParseControl".
For Mono (tested with 3.12.1) it is actually usable now.

Prerequesites:

Include "HtmlAgilityPack" from http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com

Usage:

```
String html = "<div runat=\"server\" id=\"test123\"></div>";
Control c = null;
try {
    // Performance tip: The "doc" object can be cached, if the same HTML needs to be parsed again
    var doc = new HtmlDocument();
    doc.LoadHtml(html);
    c = OwnParseControlEngine.Parse(doc);
}
catch {
    c = Page.ParseControl(html);  // Note: Will crash with Mono 3.x
}
```

Code:

```
/// <summary>
/// Own implementation of "ParseControl". Returns XHTML (default) or HTML.
/// Custom controls from "Web.config" are supported (TODO: User controls and imports on Page are NOT).
/// </summary>
private class OwnParseControlEngine {

    public class ParseException : System.Exception {
        public ParseException(HtmlNode e)
            : base("Unknown ASP.NET server-tag \"" + e.OriginalName + "\".") {
        }
    }

    private static readonly String _systemWebNamespace;
    private static readonly String _systemWebAssembly;

    private static readonly Dictionary<String, LinkedList<TagPrefixInfo>> _controlsTagPrefixInfos = new Dictionary<String, LinkedList<TagPrefixInfo>>();  // Key is tag-prefix in lowercase

    private class Factory {
        public delegate Control CreateDel(HtmlNode e);
        private readonly CreateDel _del;
        public Boolean DropWhiteSpaceLiterals { get; private set; }
        public Factory(CreateDel del, Boolean dropWhiteSpaceLiterals = false) {
            this._del = del;
            this.DropWhiteSpaceLiterals = dropWhiteSpaceLiterals;
        }
        public Control Create(HtmlNode e) {
            return this._del.Invoke(e);
        }
    }
    private static readonly Dictionary<String, Factory> _factories = new Dictionary<String, Factory>();  // Must be locked. Key is tag-name in lowercase.

    static OwnParseControlEngine() {
        // We cache the results to speed things up. "Panel" is only used to get assembly info.
        _systemWebNamespace = typeof(Panel).Namespace;
        _systemWebAssembly = typeof(Panel).Assembly.FullName;
        var section = (PagesSection)WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("/").GetSection("system.web/pages");
        foreach (TagPrefixInfo info in section.Controls) {
            LinkedList<TagPrefixInfo> l;
            if (!_controlsTagPrefixInfos.TryGetValue(info.TagPrefix, out l)) {
                l = new LinkedList<TagPrefixInfo>();
                _controlsTagPrefixInfos.Add(info.TagPrefix.ToLower(), l);
            }
            l.AddLast(info);
        }
        // Add HTML control types
        _factories.Add("span", new Factory((e) => { return new HtmlGenericControl(e.OriginalName); }));
        _factories.Add("div", new Factory((e) => { return new HtmlGenericControl(e.OriginalName); }));
        _factories.Add("body", new Factory((e) => { return new HtmlGenericControl(e.OriginalName); }));
        _factories.Add("font", new Factory((e) => { return new HtmlGenericControl(e.OriginalName); }));
        _factories.Add("a", new Factory((e) => { return new HtmlAnchor(); }));
        _factories.Add("button", new Factory((e) => { return new HtmlButton(); }));
        _factories.Add("form", new Factory((e) => { return new HtmlForm(); }));
        _factories.Add("input", new Factory((e) => {
            switch (e.Attributes["type"].Value) {
                case "button": return new HtmlInputButton();
                case "checkbox": return new HtmlInputCheckBox();
                case "file": return new HtmlInputFile();
                case "hidden": return new HtmlInputHidden();
                case "image": return new HtmlInputImage();
                case "radio": return new HtmlInputRadioButton();
                case "text": return new HtmlInputText();
                case "password": return new HtmlInputPassword();
                case "reset": return new HtmlInputReset();
                case "submit": return new HtmlInputSubmit();
            }
            throw new ParseException(e);
        }));
        _factories.Add("select", new Factory((e) => { return new HtmlSelect(); }));
        _factories.Add("table", new Factory((e) => { return new HtmlTable(); }, true));  // Adding literals not allowed
        _factories.Add("tr", new Factory((e) => { return new HtmlTableRow(); }, true));  // Adding literals not allowed
        _factories.Add("td", new Factory((e) => { return new HtmlTableCell(); }));
        _factories.Add("textarea", new Factory((e) => { return new HtmlTextArea(); }));
        _factories.Add("link", new Factory((e) => { return new HtmlLink(); }));
        _factories.Add("meta", new Factory((e) => { return new HtmlMeta(); }));
        _factories.Add("title", new Factory((e) => { return new HtmlTitle(); }));
        _factories.Add("img", new Factory((e) => { return new HtmlImage(); }));
    }

    private static void ApplyHtmlControlAttributes(HtmlControl c, HtmlNode e) {
        foreach (HtmlAttribute a in e.Attributes) {
            if (a.Name == "id")
                c.ID = a.Value;
            else if (a.Name != "runat")
                c.Attributes[a.OriginalName] = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(a.Value);
        }
    }

    private static void ApplyControlAttributes(Control c, HtmlNode e) {
        if (c is WebControl && e.Attributes["style"] != null) {
            String style = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(e.Attributes["style"].Value);
            foreach (String s in style.Split(new Char[] { ';' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
                ((WebControl)c).Style[s.Substring(0, s.IndexOf(':'))] = s.Substring(s.IndexOf(':') + 1);
        }
        foreach (PropertyInfo p in c.GetType().GetProperties()) {
            if (p.CanRead && p.CanWrite && e.Attributes[p.Name] != null) {
                try {
                    Object v = null;
                    if (p.PropertyType.IsEnum)
                        v = Enum.Parse(p.PropertyType, e.Attributes[p.Name].Value);
                    else if (p.PropertyType == typeof(String))
                        v = e.Attributes[p.Name].Value;
                    else if (p.PropertyType == typeof(Boolean))
                        v = Boolean.Parse(e.Attributes[p.Name].Value);
                    else if (p.PropertyType == typeof(Int32))
                        v = Int32.Parse(e.Attributes[p.Name].Value);
                    else if (p.PropertyType == typeof(Unit))
                        v = Unit.Parse(e.Attributes[p.Name].Value);
                    // TODO: More types?
                    if (v != null)
                        p.SetValue(c, v, null);
                }
                catch {
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static Control CreateServerControl(HtmlNode e, out Boolean dropWhiteSpaceLiterals) {                    
        Factory cf;
        lock (_factories) {
            _factories.TryGetValue(e.Name, out cf);
        }
        if (cf == null) {
            Int32 pos = e.Name.IndexOf(':');
            if (pos != -1) {
                String tagPrefix = e.Name.Substring(0, pos).ToLower();
                String name = e.Name.Substring(pos + 1);
                Type t = null;
                // Try "System.Web" (default assembly)
                if (tagPrefix == "asp")
                    t = Type.GetType(String.Format("{0}.{1}, {2}", _systemWebNamespace, name, _systemWebAssembly), false, true);  // "Namespace.ClassName, Assembly"
                if (t == null) {
                    // Try controls specified in "web.config"
                    LinkedList<TagPrefixInfo> l;
                    if (_controlsTagPrefixInfos.TryGetValue(tagPrefix, out l)) {
                        foreach (var info in l) {
                            // Custom controls
                            t = Type.GetType(String.Format("{0}.{1}, {2}", info.Namespace, name, info.Assembly), false, true);  // "Namespace.ClassName, Assembly"
                            if (t != null)
                                break;
                            // TODO: User controls with tag.TagName, tag.Source
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (t != null) {
                    cf = new Factory((e2) => { return (Control)Activator.CreateInstance(t); });
                    lock (_factories) {
                        _factories[e.Name] = cf;  // "Replace" instead of "Add", because another thread might have already added it since the lock above
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (cf == null)
            throw new ParseException(e);
        var c = cf.Create(e);
        if (c is HtmlControl)
            ApplyHtmlControlAttributes((HtmlControl)c, e);
        else
            ApplyControlAttributes(c, e);
        dropWhiteSpaceLiterals = cf.DropWhiteSpaceLiterals;
        return c;
    }

    private static void ParseChildren(Control parentC, HtmlNode currE, Boolean xhtml = true, Boolean dropWhiteSpaceLiterals = false) {
        foreach (HtmlNode childE in currE.ChildNodes) {
            Control newC = null, closeTag = null;
            Boolean newDropWhiteSpaceLiterals = false;
            if (childE.Attributes["runat"] != null && childE.Attributes["runat"].Value.ToLower() == "server")  // Server control
                newC = CreateServerControl(childE, out newDropWhiteSpaceLiterals);
            else {  // Literal control
                switch (childE.Name) {
                    case "#text":
                        if (!dropWhiteSpaceLiterals || childE.InnerText.Trim().Length != 0)
                            newC = new LiteralControl(childE.InnerText);
                        break;
                    default:
                        String s = String.Format("<{0}", childE.OriginalName);
                        foreach (HtmlAttribute a in childE.Attributes)
                            s += String.Format(" {0}=\"{1}\"", a.OriginalName, a.Value);
                        s += ">";
                        switch (childE.Name) {
                            // List of void elements taken from http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/html5/void-elements-html5/
                            case "area": case "base": case "br": case "col": case "command": case "embed": case "hr": case "img": case "input":
                            case "keygen": case "link": case "meta": case "param": case "source": case "track": case "wbr":
                                if (xhtml)
                                    s = s.Substring(0, s.Length - 1) + "/>";
                                newC = new LiteralControl(s);
                                break;
                            default:
                                newC = new PlaceHolder();  // Used as a wrapper to allow child-controls
                                newC.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(s));
                                closeTag = new LiteralControl(String.Format("</{0}>", childE.OriginalName));
                                break;
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }
            if (newC != null) {
                parentC.Controls.Add(newC);
                ParseChildren(newC, childE, xhtml, newDropWhiteSpaceLiterals);
                if (closeTag != null)
                    newC.Controls.Add(closeTag);
            }
        }
    }

    private OwnParseControlEngine() {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Parses the given HTML document and returns a Control.
    /// Throws "ParseException" on error (TODO: Maybe others too).
    /// </summary>
    public static Control Parse(HtmlDocument doc) {
        var c = new Control();
        ParseChildren(c, doc.DocumentNode, false);
        return c;
    }
}
```